# Scala: List of Arrays

Tags: scala

Consider the following snippet:

```
val mapOfArrays = (0 to 10).map{
  Array(1, 2)
}
```

I was expecting the output to be of type `List[Array[Int]]`, but it is not. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You can write this as `List.fill(11)(Array(1,2))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map call is expecting a function as a parameter, but you are passing an Array of two values. It will then try to call apply on this array with each element of the range.

I believe this is what you intended.

```
val mapOfArrays = (0 to 10).map(item => Array(1,2))
```

Comment: An array *is* a `Function1[Int, T]` (more precisely: a `Seq` is a `PartialFunction[Int, T]`) from its indices to its values, which is why the OP's code "works" in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

Running it in the REPL shows that it actually raises an exception:

```
scala> val mapOfArrays = (0 to 10).map{
     |   Array(1, 2)
     | }
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofInt.apply$mcII$sp(WrappedArray.scala:155)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofInt.apply(WrappedArray.scala:155)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofInt.apply(WrappedArray.scala:152)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:166)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
  ... 37 elided
```

This is because the code is equivalent to:

```
val mapOfArrays = (0 to 10).map{
  Array(1, 2).apply
}
```

or the more verbose

```
val mapOfArrays = (0 to 10).map{ x => 
  Array(1, 2).apply(x)
}
```

which is indeed an `IndexedSeq[Int]`.

---

The `.apply` method off `Array` returns the element at the given index, which throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `x` (from `(0 to 10)`) reachs 2.

Modifying the code so that it doesn't throw an exception:

```
scala> val mapOfArrays = (0 to 3).map{ Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) }
mapOfArrays: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

---

I'm guessing you intended to write this instead:

```
scala> val mapOfArrays = (0 to 10).map{ x =>
         Array(1, 2)
       }
mapOfArrays: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Array[Int]] = Vector(Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2))
```